# C++ Unable to call template class function after passing it to another function

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism

I have an Observable template.

```
template<typename T>
class Observable {

public:
  ~Observable() {
    observers.clear();
  }

  void registerObserver(const std::shared_ptr<Observer<T>> & observer) {
    observers.push_back(observer);
  }

  void update(const T & record) {
    for (auto &observer: observers) {
      observer->update(record);
    }
  }

private:
  std::list<std::shared_ptr<Observer<T>>> observers;
};
```

My observers are also created from a template:

```
class Observer {};

template<class T>
class Observer : public Observer {

public:
  virtual void update(const T record) = 0;
};
```

I run this like this:

```
  auto cat = Cat() 
  auto catObservable = Observable<Cat>();
  auto catObserver = std::shared_ptr<CatObserver>(); // CatObserver is a derived class from Observer<Cat> 
  observable.registerObserver(catObserver);
  observable.update(cat);
```

This code has a seg fault at runtime in the `Observable` template where it calls `observer->update(record)`. The only way to fix it is to do a dynamic cast like this:

```
  void update(const T & record) {
    for (auto &observer: observers) {
      std::shared_ptr<CatObserver> catObserver = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<CatObserver>(observer);
      catObserver->update(record);
    }
  }
```

I want to have different types of observers, and the only way I can think to make this work is have a large if statement or switch statement that tries to perform dynamic_pointer_cast to all the observers. This feels like a code smell.

I'm new to C++ and not even sure if this type of a problem is well known and what I"m trying to do here is just an anti-pattern.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You forgot to include the definition of `CatObserver`. Also, you can't have both a class `Observer` and a class template `Observer`. Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inserting null pointers and you push those in the list:

```
// catObserver is nullptr
auto catObserver = std::shared_ptr<CatObserver>();
```

Indeed, just like creating a raw pointer with no parameter, it will be null:

```
CatObserver* rawCatObserver{}; // null
```

To actually create a `CatObserver`, you have to call `std::make_shared`, which will do the dynamic allocation:

```
// returns an allocated shared pointer
auto catObserver = std::make_shared<CatObserver>();
```

> I'm new to C++ and not even sure if this type of a problem is well known and what I"m trying to do here is just an anti-pattern.

This code is okay, but performance may suffer when using `std::list` to iterate on those. For your use case, `std::vector` may be better. On a more personal note, I try to get away with `std::unique_ptr` as the ownership is more clear. And if I can get away with replacing all those classes with a `std::function` and a couple lambdas, I will usually leans towards that.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your last point? "And if I can get away with replacing all those classes with a std::function and a couple lambdas, I will usually leans towards that."

Thanks this was the root cause, just as you said.

Comment: @Beebunny In your example, you can remove the `Observer` class hierarchy completely. You could just do `template<typename T> using Observer = std::function<void(T const&)>`. At that point you can replace specific observers like `CatObserver` with a simple lambda taking a `Cat const&` as parameter.